# How to replace the names of rows in a dataframe using to_replace and regex in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a dataframe, and a series of gender. The gender series looks like this:

```
Male                                              615
male                                              206
Female                                            121
M                                                 116
female                                             62
F                                                  38
m                                                  34
f                                                  15
Make                                                4
Woman                                               3
Male                                                3
Female                                              2
Man                                                 2
Cis Male                                            2
Female (trans)                                      2
Neuter                                              1
something kinda male?                               1
Femake                                              1
```

And I'm trying to use regex to change all female related keywords to "Female". And I could do this by using:

```
survey['Gender'].replace(to_replace=r'(?i)\bfemale\b', value='Female', regex=True)
```

But for some reason, this did not change all data with the 'female' keyword such as 'Female (trans)', and I'm most sure as I checked this on Regex tester and it catches 'Female (trans)'.
Another thing I tried is to use `replace` using a dictionary. But I found that is somewhat inconvinent. 
If I want to replace all those "female" related keywords such as 'f', 'femake', 'Female (trans)', how should I do this? What kind of functions should I look into? What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.IGNORECASE` to ignore case sensitivity.

```py
obj = survey['Gender']
survey['gender'] = np.where(obj.str.contains('f|W', flags=re.IGNORECASE), 'Female', 'Male')
```

```
                   Gender   gender
0                    Male    Male
1                    male    Male
2                  Female  Female
3                       M    Male
4                  female  Female
5                       F  Female
6                       m    Male
7                       f  Female
8                    Make    Male
9                   Woman  Female
10                   Male    Male
11                 Female  Female
12                    Man    Male
13               Cis Male    Male
14         Female (trans)  Female
15                 Neuter    Male
16  something kinda male?    Male
17                 Femake  Female
```

handle exception:

```py
cond = obj.str.contains('Make|Neuter|Femake|kinda')
# obj[cond]
survey.loc[cond, 'gender'] = 'other'
```

Comment: But this gives me a problem because now I have 'Others' in the column, and when I use the ```np.where```, then it changes 'Others' to 'Male'.. How can I handle this?